# how to set Sql server Field Description in CodeFirst - Fluent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, migration

In `Sql Server` Can we set `Description` For Each Field.

[image]

I use Entity Framework and CodeFirst and I want to set "Description" for each Field.

**I searched on google but I can't find any ways to do it in  code .**

are there any way to do it ?

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080601/how-to-add-description-to-columns-in-entity-framework-4-3-code-first-using-migra

Comment: @daryal thanks a lot :)