# In EF Code First is there a data annotation for description field?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, data-annotations

While designing a table in `MS-SQL` you have a choice to add a `description` for each column you add to the table. Is it possible in `EF Code First` to do same with help of `Data Annotations`?

Comment: you need something like [Description("Here is the property discription")]  public int PropName {get;set;} will create an extra invisible for EF column in Db?

Comment: @BassamAlugili: Data annotation is like this but does this generate description in the db?

Answer (score 1):

Before you are using my soultion please read a little bit about:

**Extended Properties:**
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243(v=sql.105).aspx

**Attributes:**
http://www.dotnetperls.com/attribute

My solution will allow you to do a shadow description for any property like that:

```
[Description("My Column description!")]
public string RegionCity { get; set; }
```

**Notes:**

- Copy paste the soultion and everything should works (donnot forget the app.config connection string)!
- You can use the sql command IF NOT EXISTS to check if the extended property already exist or not.
- You can build your own generic logic or C# extension to read the descirption from any property this should be easy a just have added a an example with string.

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Linq;

  namespace EntityFrameworkDemo
  {
   using System.Data.Entity;

  public class Program
  {
      public static void Main()
      {
          Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>());


          using (var myDbContext = new MyDbContext("DefaultConnection"))
          {
              // Maybe you do not need this line!
              myDbContext.Database.Initialize(true);

              // Adding one time or use the IF NOT EXISTS SQL Command!
              var c = new ColumnsDescription();
              c.AddColumnsDescriptions(myDbContext);

              var region = new Region { RegionCity = "Test 1", RegionSeconcdCity = "Test2" };
              myDbContext.Regions.Add(region);
              myDbContext.SaveChanges();
          }


          // Reading the extended properties
          using (var myDbContext = new MyDbContext("DefaultConnection"))
          {
              var ep = "select value from fn_listextendedproperty('MS_Description','schema','dbo','table', 'Regions', 'column', 'RegionCity');";

              // For example you can read your extend property like following or you make a generic reader
              var properties = myDbContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>(ep).First();

              Console.WriteLine(properties);
          }
      }

      [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
      public class DescriptionAttribute : Attribute
      {
          string value;

          public DescriptionAttribute(string id)
          {
              this.value = id;
          }

          public string Value
          {
              get { return this.value; }
          }
      }

      public class ColumnsDescription
      {
          public void AddColumnsDescriptions(DbContext mydbContext)
          {
              // Fetch all the DbContext class public properties which contains your attributes
              var dbContextProperies = typeof(DbContext).GetProperties().Select(pi => pi.Name).ToList();

              // Loop each DbSets of type T
              foreach (var item in typeof(MyDbContext).GetProperties()
                  .Where(p => dbContextProperies.IndexOf(p.Name) < 0)
                  .Select(p => p))
              {
                  if (!item.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().Any())
                  {
                      continue;
                  }

                  // Fetch the type of "T"
                  var entityModelType = item.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                  var descriptionInfos = from prop in entityModelType.GetProperties()
                                         where prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true).Any()
                                         select new { ColumnName = prop.Name, Attributes = prop.CustomAttributes };

                  foreach (var descriptionInfo in descriptionInfos)
                  {
                      // Sql to create the description column and adding 
                      var addDiscriptionColumnSql =
                          @"sp_addextendedproperty  @name = N'MS_Description', @value = '"
                          + descriptionInfo.Attributes.First().ConstructorArguments.First()
                          + @"', @level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = dbo,  @level1type = N'Table',  @level1name = "
                          + entityModelType.Name + "s" + ", @level2type = N'Column', @level2name ="
                          + descriptionInfo.ColumnName;

                      var sqlCommandResult = mydbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(addDiscriptionColumnSql);
                  }
              }
          }
      }

      public class Region
      {
          public int Id { get; set; }

          [Description("My Column description!")]
          public string RegionCity { get; set; }

          [Description("My Second Column description!")]
          public string RegionSeconcdCity { get; set; }

      }

      public class MyDbContext : DbContext
      {
          public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }

          public MyDbContext(string connectionString)
              : base("name=" + connectionString)
          {
          }
      }
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But it is a bit complicated for my needs. Can't understand it well. Wish there were just an `attribute` for entity class that added description to database.

Comment: @afsharm this attribute is not exists in EF you have to create it by your self. there are no easy soultion for this problem with one magic line look those devleopers, they have the same problem and the have solved with migration which is a lot complicated than my soultion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080601/how-to-add-description-to-columns-in-entity-framework-4-3-code-first-using-migra

Comment: @afsharm if you need any more clarification i would be happy to help you!